# Change date format of e-mail header in Thunderbird

Tags: linux, email, thunderbird

I'm using the operating system, Ubuntu 15.10.  **How do I change the date format of the e-mail/message header in Thunderbird** from what it is now, e.g., **Mon, 11 Jan 2016 18:22:07 -0800**, to e.g., **Mon, 2016-01-11-18:22:07 -0800**?

**What I've already done**

- I've changed the Date Column in the preview pane to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS by changing my local time settings.
- I've downloaded the following add-ons and set the preferences to as closely as I can to the format I am seeking: **Change quote and reply format 0.8.6**, **Mnenhy 0.8.6.1-signed.1-let-fixed**, and **Super Date Format 1.1**.
- In Thunderbird's Config Editor, I set `changequote.headers.dateSender_custom_format` to `%D, %Y-%M-%d-%H:%i:%s`...and changed...
- `changequote.headers.date_long` to `false`
- ... some other 'date' related settings in Config Editor that I don't remember.

I may have changed enough settings to cause a conflict with a setting that might work, or maybe I haven't done enough, but I don't know.